# Find optimal Lasso/L1 regularization strength using cross validation for logistic regression in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, lasso-regression

For my logistic regression model, I would like to evaluate the optimal L1 regularization strength using cross validation (eg: 5-fold) in place of a single test-train set as shown below in my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X_scaled,y, stratify=y, test_size=0.3, 
   random_state=2)

#Evaluate L1 regularization strengths for reducing features in final model 
C = [10, 1, .1, 0.05,.01,.001] # As C decreases, more coefficients go to zero

for c in C:
    clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', C=c, solver='liblinear', class_weight="balanced")
    clf.fit(train_x, train_y)
    pred_y=clf.predict(test_x) 
    print("Model performance with Inverse Regularization Parameteter, C = 1/λ VALUE: ", c)
    cr=metrics.classification_report(test_y, pred_y)
    print(cr)
    print('')
```

Can somebody show me how to do this over 5-distinct test-train sets using cross-validation (i.e., without replicating the above code 5-times and distinct random states)?

Comment: by "distinct", do you mean 5 random splits of your original `X_scaled` dataset into different (but overlapping) training sets, or further subdividing your `x_train` into 5 sets that contain no overlap between instances?

Comment: I meant 5-random stratified splits in X and y. That is overlaps are allowed as the samples are split randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `classification_report` as a metric is not defined as a scoring metric inside `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score`. So, I will use `f1_micro` instead in the following code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

#Evaluate L1 regularization strengths for reducing features in final model 
C = [10, 1, .1, 0.05,.01,.001] # As C decreases, more coefficients go to zero

for c in C:
    clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', C=c, solver='liblinear', class_weight="balanced")
    # using data before splitting (X_scaled) and (y)
    scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_scaled, y, cv=5, scoring="f1_micro")  #<-- add this
    print(scores)  #<-- add this
```

The variable `scores` now is a list of five values representing the `f1_micro` value for your classifier over five different splits of your original data.

If you want to use another scoring metric in the `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score`, you can use the following command to get all available scoring metrics:

```
print(metrics.SCORERS.keys())
```

Also, you can use multiple scoring metrics; the following uses both `f1_micro` and `f1_macro`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

cross_validate(clf, X_scaled, y, cv=5, scoring=["f1_micro", "f1_macro"])
```

Comment: awesome -I already used cross_val_score for other metrics, and never considered to do so for regularization strengths.

Comment: Can you please update the code fully above to fill in the blanks?

Comment: yeah, sure. Here you go

Comment: @Anwaric - After additional review,  I am a little dissatisfied with the above suggestion as it evaluates effect of L1 regularization strength on only a single random split of X and y data (random_state = 2 in above example).         
  How can one rejig this code such that it does the L1 regularization strength evaluation across multiple random stratified splits of the data? That was my original question - and maybe not very clear in my replies to you.

Comment: I've edited my answer... I've commented the parts that are no longer necessary. Also, I've added some more notes

Comment: THanks @Anwarvic! It works great. I am accepting your answer, but please consider removing all the commented/unnecessary code.